# Determine if upcoming birthday is within 7 days

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, date

I'm trying to determine whether to show a tag of an upcoming birthday or not by this boolean logic that I'm a bit lost at.

```
const birthDayDate = new Date('1997-09-20');
const now = new Date();
const today = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate(), 0, 0, 0);
const threshold = new Date(today).setDate(today.getDate() + 8);
console.log(birthDayDate >= today && birthDayDate < new Date(threshold));
```

This is the code piece that I have and would like it to console.log true if an upcoming birthday is within 7 days margin.

Now, given that today and as of writing this post in my timezone it is 09.14.2022, I would like it to console.log the right result which would be true, given that the date we are comparing with is in 6days not taking years into the account.

Comment: You are comparing if the birthDayDate is greater than today. How can a day in 1997 be over a day in 2022?

Comment: This question is almost certainly a duplicate of other SO questions but many of the answers to those seem to have subtle errors (daylight saving time, time zones) and not-so-subtle errors (dates close to the start/end of a calendar year) that make this whole topic a minefield.  I'm *supposed* to close this as a duplicate of those as long as the *questions* are essentially they same, but ugh, I don't know what to do here.

Comment: Oh goodness the same type of answers are appearing here with the same issues.  I'm going to close this as a duplicate of others, and people can work out how to deal with calendars over there, sorry. 

Answer (score 0):

> You are comparing if the birthDayDate is greater than today. How can a day in 1997 be over a day in 2022?

A possible solution is to change the year of the birthDayDate to this year, then check if that date is within 7 days of today:

```js
const birthDayDate = new Date('1997-09-20');
const thisYear = new Date(birthDayDate)
thisYear.setYear(new Date().getFullYear());
const now = new Date();
console.log(thisYear - now <= 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7 && thisYear - now >= 0);
```

`1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7` is just 7 days in milliseconds.

We also have to check if the date is past today with `thisYear - now >= 0`.

Comment: And if the birthday is January 2nd while the current date is December 31?

Answer (score 0):

Try this it also checks if dates are passed after birth date then it will return false.

```js
 const birthDayDate = new Date("1997-09-20");
 const now = new Date();

 const after_threshold = new Date(now.getFullYear(),birthDayDate.getMonth(),birthDayDate.getDate(),0,0,0);

 const before_threshold = new Date(now.getFullYear(),birthDayDate.getMonth(),birthDayDate.getDate() + 8,0,0,0);

 console.log(before_threshold >= now && after_threshold <= now);
```

Comment: And if the birthday is January 2nd while the current date is December 31?